# What is the process in finding all angle solutions to $\cos(5x)+\cos(x)=2\cos(2x) $

Tags: trigonometry

So I've been getting into multiple angle equations into trigonometry, and have no problems 'solving' the equations, I really don't know what to do after $x+360k$.

I just cant seem to find all the possible angles, and I loose a lot of time trying to discriminate them. Can anyone help me?

For example:

$\cos(5x)+\cos(x)=2\cos(2x) $

$x=0;45;120;135;225;240;315$

I couldn't find the 315 angle and mostly just feel like I'm playing around the unit circle. What do I have to do?

Comment: How did you find the other ones in a way such that you didn't find $315^\circ$?

Answer (score 1):

Rearrange the equation

\begin{align}
\cos 5x+\cos x-2\cos2x
&=2\cos3x\cos2x-2\cos2x\\
&=2\cos2x(\cos3x-1)=0
\end{align}

which has two sets of the solutions in terms of integer $n$,

$$\cos2x =0\implies 
x =\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{n\pi}{2}$$

$$\cos3x =1\implies 
x =\frac{2n\pi}{3}$$

Answer (score 0):

Solving thois equation requires factorisation of the l.h.s.

Uou need the factorisation formula 
$$\cos(a+b)+\cos(a-b)=2\cos a \cos b, $$
so that the l.h.s. besomes
$$ \cos 5x +\cos x=2\cos 3x $$

Answer (score 0):

Solving this equation requires factorisation of the l.h.s.

You need the factorisation formula: 
$$\cos(a+b)+\cos(a-b)=2\cos a \cos b, $$
so that the l.h.s. besomes
$$ \cos 5x +\cos x=2\cos 3x \cos 2x,$$
so the initial equation splits into

1. $\cos 2x=0\;$ or
2. $\cos 3x=1$.